# Can we have multiple "WITH AS" in single sql - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I had a very simple question: Does oracle allow multiple "WITH AS" in a single sql statement.

Example:

```
WITH abc AS( select ......)

WITH XYZ AS(select ....) /*This one uses "abc" multiple times*/

Select ....   /*using XYZ multiple times*/
```

I can make the query work by repeating the same query multiple times, but do not want to do that, and leverage "WITH AS".
It seems like a simple requirement but oracle does not allow me:

> ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Answer (score 286, accepted):

You can do this as:

```
WITH abc AS( select
             FROM ...)
, XYZ AS(select
         From abc ....) /*This one uses "abc" multiple times*/
  Select 
  From XYZ....   /*using abc, XYZ multiple times*/
```

Comment: Can we use alias from the first subquery to the second subquery? In this case the `abc` and `xyz` subqueries? I need to get the result of the first subquery and use it on the second subquery.

Comment: @Wax I'm able to use the aliases from the first subquery in the second subquery with no problem, just like the answer above suggests. I was also able to use aliases and columns from both tables in the main query.

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: thanks... I was re-using the keyword "with" before both statements. Your answer clarified my issue.

Answer (score 45):

the correct syntax is -

```
with t1
as
(select * from tab1
where conditions...
),
t2
as
(select * from tab2
where conditions...
(you can access columns of t1 here as well)
)
select * from t1, t2
where t1.col1=t2.col2;
```

Comment: "you can access columns of t1 here as well" was very helpful to point out.

Answer (score 18):

Yes you can...

```
WITH SET1 AS (SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL), -- SET1 initialised
     SET2 AS (SELECT * FROM SET1)        -- SET1 accessed
SELECT * FROM SET2;                      -- SET2 projected

10/29/2013 10:43:26 AM
```

Follow the order in which it should be initialized in Common Table Expressions

Answer (score 4):

Aditya or others, can you join or match up t2 with t1 in your example, i.e. translated to my code,

```
with t1 as (select * from AA where FIRSTNAME like 'Kermit'),
     t2 as (select * from BB B join t1 on t1.FIELD1 = B.FIELD1)
```

I am not clear whether only WHERE is supported for joining, or what joining approach is supported within the 2nd WITH entity.  Some of the examples have the WHERE A=B down in the body of the select "below" the WITH clauses.

The error I'm getting following these WITH declarations is the identifiers (field names) in B are not recognized, down in the body of the rest of the SQL.  So the WITH syntax seems to run OK, but cannot access the results from t2.

Comment: You need to alia t1 within the t2 with clause

Comment: How can i reference with clause table inside sub query ? it's throwing an error. for example, WITH SET1 AS (SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL), -- SET1 initialised
     SET2 AS (SELECT * FROM SET1)        -- SET1 accessed
SELECT * FROM SET2 LEFT OUTER JOIN (select * from SET1 where sysdate = now()) set3 on set1.sysdate = set3.sysdate;