# SQL query to get grouped sums and concatenated lists, preferably without using functions

Tags: oracle, plsql, concatenation

I have a table like

```
colA    colB    colC
A        10      1
A        20      2
A        30      3
B        10      1
B        20      2
```

I want an output like this

```
ColA  colB  colC
A      60    1,2,3
B      30    1,2
```

Can someone tell me how to do it with and without using functions, and in PL/SQL?

Comment: You have to use functions, so no is the answer.

Comment: You have this tagged for [mysql] and [plsql]. MySQL does not support PL/SQL, which is only available for Oracle and IBM's DB2, as far as I'm aware. Did you mean to tag this for [oracle] instead of [mysql]?

Comment: yes my bad i meant to tag this for oracle

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is sql you needed.
Note : it will only run on oracle 11g R2 onwards.

```
   with tab as( 
    select 'A' col1,10 col2,1 col3 from dual union all
    select 'A' col1,20 col2,2 col3 from dual union all
    select 'A' col1,30 col2,3 col3 from dual union all
    select 'B' col1,10 col2,1 col3 from dual union all
    select 'B' col1,20 col2,2 col3 from dual )
    select  col1, sum(col2),listagg(col3,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col3) AS col3_list 
    from tab group by col1
```

Comment: it is just dummy name given to column I think I must change it.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your table name is tab

```
with tab1(col1, col2) as (
  select colA, sum(colB) 
  from tab group by colA
),
tab2(col1, col2) as (
  select colA, LISTAGG(TO_CHAR(colC),',')
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY colC)
  from tab group by colA
)
select a.col1, a.col2, b.col2 
from tab1 a, tab2 b 
where a.col1 = b.col1
```

OutPut:

```
COL1  COL2  COL2
A     60    1,2,3
B     30    1,2
```

For more information about `LISTAGG` [link](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=515)

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654494/can-we-have-multiple-with-as-in-single-sql-oracle-sql) explains about `multiple with clause`

Or simply;

```
select colA, sum(colB) colB,LISTAGG(TO_CHAR(colC),',')
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY colC)
  from tab group by colA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Probably this may the easiest solution syntactically :)

SELECT COLA,
  SUM(COLB),
  WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(COLC)
FROM
  (SELECT 'A' cola,10 AS colb,1 AS colc FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'A' cola,20 AS colb,2 AS colc FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'A' cola,30 AS colb,3 AS colc FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'B' cola,10 AS colb,1 AS colc FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'B' cola,20 AS colb,2 AS colc FROM dual
  )
GROUP BY COLA ;
```

## OUTPUT

COLA    SUM(COLB)   WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(COLC)
A   60           1,2,3

## B   30           1,2