# How can I reference first table from second table in an Oracle WITH clause? CTE

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I read here:

[Can we have multiple "WITH AS" in single sql - Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654494/can-we-have-multiple-with-as-in-single-sql-oracle-sql)

that if I have 2 tables in my WITH clause, I can reference the first tables in the my second table's where clause. However, I have had no luck doing this in practice. Any insights would be appreciate.

I've tried every iteration of aliases that I can think of when trying to access the first table.

```
with term as (
select course_reference_number, academic_period  from student_course ),
    term2 as (
select subject_desc, academic_period from student_course where 
and term.course_reference_number = 22638) 

select term.*, term2.* 
from term, term2 
where term.academic_period= term2.academic_period;
```

I get the error: ORA-00904: "TERM"."COURSE_REFERENCE_NUMBER": invalid identifier

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  Your query doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `term.course_reference_number` in query of `term2` without using `term` in from clause.

Please note that `term` is not in the scope of `term2` untill it is used in from clause of `term2`.

You can achieve the desired result by moving `WHERE` clause of `term2` to the final query as following:

```
with term as (
select course_reference_number, academic_period  from student_course ),

    term2 as (
select subject_desc, academic_period from student_course) 

select term.*, term2.* 
from term join term2 
On (term.academic_period= term2.academic_period)
Where term.course_reference_number = 22638;
```

Suggestion: always use ansi standard joins.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can reference the first CTE in the second one, but - you have to do it properly. I don't know what you want to do, but this example shows how you might have done it.

Test case first:

```
SQL> create table student_course
  2    (course_Reference_Number number,
  3     academic_period         number,
  4     subject_desc            varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into student_Course values (1, 100, 'Math');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into student_Course values (2, 200, 'Science');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into student_Course values (22638, 300, 'Biology');

1 row created.
```

Your query:

```
SQL> with
  2    term as
  3      (select s.course_Reference_number,
  4              s.academic_period
  5       from student_course s
  6      ),
  7    term2 as
  8      (select s.subject_desc,
  9              s.academic_period
 10       from student_course s join
 11            term t                        --> yes, you can reference the first CTE
 12            on t.academic_period = s.academic_period
 13       where t.course_Reference_number = 22638
 14      )
 15  select t1.*,
 16         t2.*
 17  from term t1 join term2 t2 on t1.academic_period = t2.academic_period;

COURSE_REFERENCE_NUMBER ACADEMIC_PERIOD SUBJECT_DESC         ACADEMIC_PERIOD
----------------------- --------------- -------------------- ---------------
                  22638             300 Biology                          300

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos in your query.

You have an extra `and` in for starters. Try this:

```
with 

term as ( 
    select course_reference_number, academic_period 
    from student_course ), 
term2 as ( 
    select subject_desc, academic_period 
    from student_course 
    where term.course_reference_number = 22638)

select term.*, term2.* 
from term, term2 
where term.academic_period = term2.academic_period;
```